# Bindings Events dynamically to Table rows & Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to apply click event on only second column & click event on the third column's button, but event is not triggering.

html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <tr>
        <td class="webIcon">
        <img src="Img/icon.png"></img>
        </td>
        <td class="tabTitle tabRow">Smith</td> 
        <td class="closeTab">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm " aria-label="Left Align">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

jquery:

```
 $( '.table tr:nth-child(2)').delegate("td","click",function(){
            $('.tabRow').click(function(){
                var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
                console.log(id);
            });
        });

  $( '.table tr:nth-child(3)').delegate("td","click",function(){
            $('.button').click(function(){
                var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
                console.log(id);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are these TRs statics??? Are these TRs available in DOM at time you are trying to bind click event?  Why are you trying to delegate event? (could be many good reasons, just wondering?)

Comment: @A.Wolff because i am adding rows to the table dynamically

Comment: So if the rows (TRs) are added dynamically, delegate event to TABLE level (if static): `$('.table').delegate("tr:nth-child(2) td","click",function(){...});`  FYI, `delegate()` has been superseded by `.on('click', 'selector', handler);`

Comment: @A.Wolff the row in the html is for example... before loading the html i will clear the contents of the table and freshly add rows from another js file. hence to bind events to the rows added dynamically in the table so we need to use delegate (or) bind (or) On API of jquery

Comment: Ya but to delegate event, the parent must be static otherwise delegation cannot work: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @A.Wolff fine what changes should i do here

Comment: I already posted it as comment: `$('.table').delegate("tr:nth-child(2) td","click",function(){...});` Will work if `.table` element(s) is/are static and available in DOM at time you are binding events

Answer (score 5):

Your code is more complex. Try this

```
$( '.table .tabTitle').on("click",function(){            
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(id);            
});

$( '.table .btn').on("click",function(){           
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

```js
$('.table .tabTitle').on("click", function() {

  var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
  console.log(id);

});

$('.table .btn').on("click", function() {

  var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
  console.log(id);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr id="ID1">
    <td class="webIcon">
      <img src="Img/icon.png"></img>
    </td>
    <td class="tabTitle tabRow">Smith</td>
    <td class="closeTab">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm " aria-label="Left Align">Button
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit:

- Avoid nth-child(n) selectors if you can because that affects the load performance of your page.

Comment: will this work even if i had more rows dynamically..??

Comment: Yes!.... try it.. You need to make sure the classes remain the same on dynamic tds

Comment: No it won't, no need to try it! ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff you should read this http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/ and instead of No arguments, put your time on providing solution

Comment: @Dipaks That's a good link, indeed you are correct, OP should avoid using it if possible

Comment: console.log() is not supported in jsfiddle, but you can always use an alert to show that it works :)... http://jsfiddle.net/pe98vgdh/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should delegate event to closest static parent container. For example, if .table element(s) is/are static and available in DOM at time you are binding events:

```
$('.table').delegate("tr .tabRow, tr .btn","click",function(){
     var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
     console.log(id);
});
```

Be aware:

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.
>   For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to
>   use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation
>   is in the .on() method. In general, these are the equivalent templates
>   for the two methods:

```
// jQuery 1.4.3+
$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
// jQuery 1.7+
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Comment: @Wolff it works but as soon as i click the row both row & button events are triggering.

Comment: @iHappyk You have to stop propagation for BUTTON event and not nesting handler  EDIT: ok, i'll update answer, i didn't saw at first you were nesting handlers, which doesn't really make sense

Comment: @iHappyk Just one thing, there is no element with class `button` in your posted code as suggested by this selector `.button`. Do you mean instead element of type BUTTON or class `.btn`? And do you target instead the cell (TD) `nth-child` element? Itsn't clear what you are expecting in fact?!  `i am trying to apply click event on only second column & click event on the third column's button.` So you aren't targeting ROW but cell. I updated answer reflecting how i understand (finally) question

Comment: sorry its .btn ,yes my target is on cell

Comment: @iHappyk Anyway, there is no TR with any ID set in your posted code. Next time when asking question, describe expected behaviour and post **relevant** code in question

Answer (score 0):

delegate has been superseded by the .on() method (more info about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) so I'm going to use "on" instead of "delegate" (hope you don't mind).

Following your code style, you could try something like:

```
$('.table').on("click", "tr td:nth-child(3)", function () {
    $(this).find("button").off('click').on('click', function() {// Remove the click event firstly or you'll end up with a pile of them
        var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
    });
});
```

I'd do it this way though:

```
$('.table').on("click", "tr td:nth-child(3) button", function () {
    //$(this).find("button").off('click').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
    //});
});
```